# Need help keeping my process running until I type in a keyword

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Write a main method that creates and starts the game. The user should
be able to enter letters repeatedly. After each entry, the current playing field should
be issued. When the user enters x, the program is to be terminated.
That is my excerice.

I tried to do it with a do/while loop, but I just couldnt make it work. Then I tried to do it with a `RuntimeException` and use try/catch but I also failed.
If someone could just hint me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it :).

```
public class SpaceInvaders {

    private static final char[][] field = new char[5][8];
    static int x = (int) ((Math.random() * 8));

    public static void field(){
        Arrays.fill(field[0], 'o');
        for(int k=1; k<5; k++){
            Arrays.fill(field[k],' ');
        }
        field[4][x] = 'V';
        outputArray();
    }
    public static void outputArray(){
        for (char[] chars : field) {
            for (char aChar : chars) {
                System.out.print(aChar + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void move(char input){
        if(input == 'a'){
            if(x == 0){
                x++;
            }
            field[4][x] = ' ';
            field[4][x - 1] = 'V';
            outputArray();
        }
        else if(input == 'd'){
            if(x == 7){
                x--;
            }
            field[4][x] = ' ';
            field[4][x + 1] = 'V';
            outputArray();
        }
        else if(input == 'x'){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        field();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include a detailed problem description in your question. A simple "I just couldnt make it work" is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a loop around your scanner waiting for keyboard input

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    field();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        move(s.next().trim().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: wow its actually that ease huh? thanks you very much. I've been losing my mind over this one.

Comment: @Filip If this resolved your problem, please check the check mark next to this answer

Comment: @tobo1987 is all its doing, that the code inside is infinitly repeated until something stops it?

Comment: @Filip Yes. Infinitely repeated until something stops it. And the thing that stops it in this case is System.exit(0)